# Is it necessary to make a careers profile public for employers to view it?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, cv

I created a profile on Careers 2.0. I have applied to a few positions through Careers 2.0. Each application has a View Profile link. But I see that the counter for employer views in my profile is still 0. Is it because that the profile setting is private in my privacy settings?

My understanding was that I could keep my profile private, but the employers would be able to view it. Or is it that the employers have not viewed the profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you apply with your profile anonymously (not logged in when applying), employers can only see the resume you upload.  When you apply with your profile when logged in, employers can see your profile, private or not.  Employer views only increment when employers view your profile in profile search, so if you apply with your profile, it will not affect your view counter.

Comment: "Employer views only increment when employers view your profile in profile search...". That explains it. Thank you Nick.